# Key-Value Array from csv with just two columns in spreadsheet

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv, generated with Open Office Spreadsheet, separator is comma, text wrapper is ".

I want just to columns in my spreadsheet, as it is some key-value list,
like:

```
a -> b
aa -> bb
aaa -> bbb
```

so my spreadsheet has just two columns, each row containing a key-value pair, each key in a cell, each value in a cell. But when I use

```
if ($_FILES ['userfile'] ['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK &&
    is_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['userfile'] ['tmp_name'] )) {

        $csvfile = file_get_contents ( $_FILES ['userfile'] ['tmp_name'] );
    }

    $dict = str_getcsv($csvfile);
```

And var_dump $dict afterwards, i get

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(6) "b "aa"" [2]=> 
            string(8) "bb "aaa"" [3]=> string(3) "bbb" }
```

See index 1, where the first value "b" and the seconde key "aa" are stored in one index.

OpenOffice places no comma behind the values, aka before a new row. 
How do I avoid that two strings end up in one index? 
Can I somehow tell str_getcsv that when two " follow each other, it's also a separator? Or can I add a third column always containing # and say "if it contains #, its a line break? (I tried, and couldn't manage..)
Or is there even a function, that expects key, value, linebreak in csv?

Whats the correct way to do this? I'm sure people done this so often, but I don't know how to google it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `fgetcsv()` ?
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

It reads line by line, there's an example in the link.

Comment: Um.. Well.. this.. does it.. :) Thanks ^^ ( I missed the forest for the trees.. and never done that task before..)

Comment: You're welcome, I had my fair share of headaches with CSV and PHP :D